# Dynamically generating cards in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, get

I have a card that I would like to replicate for every new image I receive from the mock database. This is supposed to very much resemble instagram. When I `console.log(data[i])` within the `for...loop` everything prints just fine. I have also tested       `$('.card').clone().insertAfter('.card')` and it works independently. Putting it together with setting the new attribute does not work. I am not sure what is going wrong.

UPDATED: https://jsfiddle.net/5vant14u/1/
Each image should be different.

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="image">
      <img class="feedImg" src="test.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="likeBar">
      <ul >
        <li class="heart">
          <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="likes">
          <span>TEMPORARY USER</span>

        </li>
        <li class="moreInfo">
          <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-lg"></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="commentDiv">
      <span>THIS WILL BE USERNAME</span>
      <p>BODY OF THE POST</p>
    </div>

    <div class="newCommentDiv">
      <input type="text">
    </div>

  </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get('https://image-server-codesmith.firebaseapp.com/images', function(data, status) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $('.feedImg').attr('src', data[i])
      $('.card').clone().insertAfter('.card')
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: `.feedImg` is a global lookup, so that is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first clone it and then set the image to the clone.

$(‘.card’).clone().find(‘.img’).attr(‘src’, data[i])

Comment: When I do this it is indeed now showing all of the images from the database, but it is doing it independently of the card. Each image is displayed after the main card, not the card being duplicated with the image within it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. But its insanely slow as cloning produces a deep copy. You can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get('https://image-server-codesmith.firebaseapp.com/images', function(data) {
    // Save the outerHTML of the card, which will later help us create its siblings
    let card_html = $('.card')[0].outerHTML
    // By appending [0] to the jQuery object will expose the first actual html element from DOM
    // [0] is basically the first element of the array, you can do [1], which will return the second matching html element from the dom
    
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // outerHTML is a string, we need to convert it to an jquery element so we can find 'feedImg' and replace its attribute
      // $('<div>Hello </div>') will create a div element which can be used anywhere by appending to the DOM
      let new_card = $(card_html)
      
      // New card holds a jquery element, so we can use find to locate .feedImg and update its src attribute
      new_card.find('.feedImg').attr('src', data[i]);
      
      // new_card jquery element now has the updated src, we append it to card's parent
      $('.card').parent().append(new_card)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="image">
    <img class="feedImg" src="test.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="likeBar">
    <ul>
      <li class="heart">
        <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="likes">
        <span>TEMPORARY USER</span>

      </li>
      <li class="moreInfo">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-lg"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="commentDiv">
    <span>THIS WILL BE USERNAME</span>
    <p>BODY OF THE POST</p>
  </div>

  <div class="newCommentDiv">
    <input type="text">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This very much works but I am getting the exact same image over and over. Also the css is WAY off. Is that normal for this type of thing?

Comment: I edited the original post to show a jsfiddle link. here it is as well. https://jsfiddle.net/5vant14u/1/

Comment: It works great now. I am going to dig into the docs to try to understand this code a bit better. Do you mind if I ask for a short explanation of what is going on with your jQuery code? especially the ```$('.card')[0]```

Comment: @tryingCode Added comments for your understanding